# Using diff (v) or D(v) in matlab

Tags: matlab, diff, differentiation

I have an equation given by the formula. Its actually charge a variable capacitor given by the following relation.

**q=c(v)*dv**...........Equation (1)

c(v) is a function of v and v is just s sine wave defined in matlab as under.

```
t = 0:0.01:5;
f=0.2;
v = 5*sin(2*pi*f*t);
```

c(v) can be any function dependent of v.

**What I want to do ?**

I want to calculate the capacitor charge given by equation (1)...
But I am confused about the term "dv" . This is actually the differential of "v". Should I calculate it using the matlab function **"diff"** or **"D"**???

Like

```
dv=diff(v)
```

Is this right?

Comment: Are you sure Equation 1 isn't `dq = c(v) * dv`? This would be the equation for a voltage-dependent capacitor.

Comment: @Juderb is correct, which mean AK only really needs to know how _C_ varies with _V_, and how _V_ varies with _t_ is not relevant. Once _C(V)_ is known it should be integrated, not differentiated.

Comment: @RPM Thanks for pointing it out. I did a huge novice mistake in my deleted answer.

Comment: @Juderb,,Yes I did a mistake in writing the equation. Now I have corrected it. Its an equation of variable capacitor.

Comment: @RPM,,,,. Now I have corrected it. Its an equation of variable capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB offers the surprisingly-named function `integral` to calculate the definite integral of a function *c*: **R**→**R** between the limits 0 and *V*:

```
Q = integral(@c, 0, V);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I really appreciate it. I made a mistake in writing the equation previously, which I have corrected now. Its q= c(v)*dv ......